# Авторизация на сайте через Steam

Tags: авторизация, steam-web-api

Нужно сделать авторизацию на сайте через *Steam*.

Я так понимаю, ссылка с моего сайта должна вести на [SteamOpenid](http://steamcommunity.com/openid).
Что нужно делать дальше?